# How can I generate knowledge base article with salesforce AI?

Tags: einstein, ai, generative

I have explored trailheads https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/einstein-for-service-quick-look/deliver-smarter-service-with-artificial-intelligence and salesforce help site, but I still don't understand how can I enable or deploy generative AI in Salesforce, for example, including Knowledge Article creation or generation using generative AI?

Comment: it has nothing common with the question posted

Comment: @RohitKamble and the comment is still spam from a "marketing" team member from that questionable (at best) operation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to achieve in Winter'24 release, however, this might be available in Spring'24 or later releases